# Transformer less Power supply's waveform is Noisy

Tags: voltage-measurement, transformerless

Hi I want to measure the mains voltage using transformerless power supply. the output of the supply is fed to an optocoupler and later read by a microcontroller.

The problem i am having is that the waveform obtained from the supply is very noisy.

[image]

the schematic is posted below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnZTXo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is whether transformerless power supply circuits are always noisy??
and can they be used for measuring purposes
A circuit lab simulation shows a neat looking rectified sine wave.
Please Advise. 
[image]

Comment: How did you connect the ground lead from the scope probe? Is this noise also present on the incoming ac line?

Comment: You need to have the probe's ground wire connected to get a decent measurement. You are on dangerous ground now...the probe's ground wire may be connected to **earth ground** inside the scope so you must connect it to earth ground in your circuit. Please don't go any further with this circuit unless you can take proper safety precautions working with mains (deadly) voltages.

Comment: You have misunderstood me.the probe ground wire is connected to the circuit . the ground pin on the power chord is isolated by using tape.

Comment: Why don't you have a smoothing capacitor?

Comment: using a  large smoothing capacitor drops the peak of the wave and a small one doesnt filter it properly. also is there any other way to measure mains voltage without the use of a transformer ??

Comment: The lack of a smoothing capacitor is the entire reason your circuit is so noisy. It will only drop the peak while the capacitor is charging; after a few mains cycles it will be fully charged and not drop the peak voltage anymore.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the case because different values of capacitors drop the peak to different values. i also waited for quite some time for the capacitor to charge up

Comment: @FarvezFarook Then wherever you're putting them is not the right place to put them. As others have said, though, this circuit is rather dangerous and could very well blow up your oscilloscope to boot... I would recommend learning a bit more about how electronics works before doing anything mains-powered. Alkaline batteries are your friend.

Comment: the smoothing capacitor is placed parallel to the load resistor R3.

Answer (score 0):

The transformerless power supply circuit is essentially a high pass filter. so on the output of the resistor we will get the high frequency components of the input signal only. Thus the noisy wave form.

F=1/(2 pi R C)
the cut off frequency of the filter according to the resistor and capacitor values was 3.3 Khz
So the output waveform is only above 3.3khz

Comment: Unless you are operating this circuit off of a poorly regulated generator, your (fundamental) input frequency will not change. The frequency tolerance of the grid is at least an order of magnitude greater than the components you are using. The noise you are seeing is not likely to be harmonics of the fundamental AC frequency. Incorrect probing technique and/or local generators of noise are more likely suspects.

Comment: i used capacitive voltage dropper to get the required current for the optocoupler' led without wasting much power as compared to resistive dropper. can capacitive dropper provide accurate information of the mains voltage . also can u suggest proper probing techniques